# ucwords() is not capitalizing the field text with UPDATE query

Tags: sql-update, capitalize

i have a name filed which has all the words in lower case. I want to update field as first letter as capital of all words of complete table at once.

im trying the below code which is updating/replacing the field for all rows:

```
$queryP = "madinah hi madinah";
$queryD = ucwords($queryP);
$pupdt  =   mysql_query("
update media_detail
set test = '$queryD'
");
```

and the below is not working:

```
$queryP     = $row['unique_name'];
$queryD = ucwords($queryP);
$pupdt  =   mysql_query("
update media_detail
set test = '$queryD'
");
```

please help im not getting it to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct except that you should do updates in the loop. I also added the data retrieval step (that you probably omitted for brevity) which precedes the loop. Here is the complete code:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, unique_name FROM media_detail";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $queryP = ucwords($row['unique_name']);
    $pupdt  =   mysql_query("
        UPDATE media_detail
        SET test = $queryP
        WHERE id = $id
    ");
    $conn->query($pupdt);
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? What are you getting as a result? Does anything gets updated? And in your second code snippet above: what happens if you do `echo $queryD;` after the second line - this way you'll at least know `ucwords($queryP);` is working.

Comment: well it is updating the field awfully with one of the thousands of names. like it is updating 'Name 798' to all rows.
otherwise if you go for echo it is working perfect.

Comment: But you did put the update statement inside the while loop as I suggested, right? Because what you're describing is exactly the behavior of your original code that does update only single value. If my code above doesn't work what you can do is to put `echo $id." ".$row['unique_name']." ".$queryP."<br>";` on line that follows `$queryP` assignment - that way you will see how many lines in the table were read and processed. And/or you can use counter for the number of lines processed and output its value in the end.

Comment: worked fine.. thanks alot... i was just using the update in the same while loop of the query with mysql_fetch_array...